# gmock template class 'const T1': actual parameter with requested alignment of 64 won't be aligned

Tags: c++, c++11, googletest, googlemock

I am trying to gmock the following template class

```
template <typename Type>
class Interface {
  public:
    virtual bool insert(const Type& param);

}
```

by using gmock as follows

```
template <typename Type>

class CMockInterface: public Interface<Type> {

MOCK_METHOD1_T(insert, bool(const Type&));

}
```

when building I get the following errors

error C2718: 'const T1': actual parameter with requested alignment of 64 won't be aligned

note: see reference to class template instantiation 'testing::internal::ImplicitlyConvertible<const T &,testing::internal::BiggestInt>' being compiled

what is this error?

Comment: It compiles fine to me with GCC and Clang (couldn't really get gtest to work with MSVC on godbolt): https://godbolt.org/z/P4dPdaMvo

Comment: And with what `Type` you create your `CMockInterface`?

Comment: I create it with a struct type that has 2 elements a fixed vector and an integer 32

Comment: Don't describe it, show it.

Comment: `class Interface` must have the virtual destructor `virtual ~Interface() = default;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/2054) in GoogleTest, and was [fixed a while ago](https://github.com/google/googletest/commit/f31bf1d362afa1eba7efdc5bc0a33b0e814ce43a). Try updating GoogleTest to at least 1.10.0.

Comment: cherry-picked the fix. worked. thanks (y)